# XML document from class path resource [beans.xml] is invalid

Tags: java, spring, spring-bean

Hi everyone I'm learning this new thing in java and I got this code from some source but when I'm trying to run this code on my system I'm getting this error while running my code and here is the complete error that I am getting and as I'm not able to resolve this error

```
Aug 05, 2020 8:08:40 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [beans.xml]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 5 in XML document from class path resource [beans.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Document root element "beans", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 75; Document root element "beans", must match DOCTYPE root "null".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:204)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:135)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:396)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:327)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:284)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.rootElementSpecified(XMLDTDValidator.java:1601)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:1879)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(XMLDTDValidator.java:744)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1361)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1329)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:3134)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:867)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:605)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:507)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:867)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:796)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:142)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:247)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:126)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:125)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:65)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:226)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:58)
    at com.beans.run.run.main(run.java:11)
```

I'm using this java code in run.java file

```
package com.beans.run;


import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class run {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("[+] running [+]");
        ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
        hello hw = (hello) ctx.getBean("helloWorld");
        hw.getMessage();
    }

}
```

and this code in hello.java file

```
package com.beans.run;

public class hello {

        private String message;

        public void setMessage(String message){
            this.message  = message;
        }
        public void getMessage(){
            System.out.println("Your Message : " + message);
        }
}
```

here is my beans.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
    <bean id="helloWorld" class="com.beans.hello">
        <property name="message" value="Hello World"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I've tried all possible solution but it did'nt work please help me to figure this out

Comment: The package defined in the xml is `com.beans` and the real one is `com.beans.run`

Comment: so I have to change package from `com.beans.hello` to `com.beans.run` ? or should I add a doctype ?

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you're using a 10-year-old setup for a new application?

Comment: yeah I am working on java-8 with beans due to a specific reason

Comment: just change the right party of the xml file to `class="com.beans.run.hello"` or the class package to `com.beans`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
<bean id="s1" class="com.project.Sim1"></bean>
<bean id="s2" class="com.project.Sim2"></bean>
</beans>
```

So this is my XML file.
I was facing the same error too and I tried everything mentioned already but nothing worked.

First of all, I had changed http to https which was causing the error for me.
But if i used http eclipse would show an error and it would vanish when i used https. But that would cause the error mentioned in your question or a different error that goes like
"Line 5 of XML...".

So, ignore the white cross mark and run it anyway. You'll then get the output.
I spent one full day trying to fix this error and the next day I changed https to http and ignored the cross marks and ran it anyway and it worked lol.. funny